# Correct way to set yaml_column_permitted_classes for a custom class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Because of [this security advisory](https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/cve-2022-32224-possible-rce-escalation-bug-with-serialized-columns-in-active-record/81017) serialized attributes need to use YAML.safe_load with a safe list of allowed Classes.

The problem I am having is that I want to use a custom class (Foo::Bar) and it seems like at least in Rails 6.1 that you need to set the allowed classes towards the beginning of the boot process in `application.rb`.

```rb
    config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [
      Symbol,
      String,
      Foo::Bar
    ]
```

The problem is that running this (as is) inside `application.rb` gives this error:

```
 uninitialized constant AppName::Application::Foo (NameError)
```

If I add to the top of the `application.rb` a require statement, then the application boots fine, but, in dev I then get warnings (because classes and their constants are redefined)

```rb
 warning: previous definition of SomeConstant was here
```

The only cleanish way I've found is instead of using the config at all, you just set what rails *really wants* to be set which is this ->

```rb
# in some initializer
ActiveRecord::Base.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [
      Symbol,
      String,
      Foo::Bar
]
```

That doesn't give any errors, but, it feels like I'm going outside of what Rails wants me to do.

Is there a *correct* way to initialize custom classes in the `application.rb` ?

Answer (score 5):

On Rails 7 what I have found is to put things into an initializer (I use `config/initializers/active_record.rb` and use the `Rails.application.config.after_initialize` hook.

You end up with something like this:

```
# config/initializers/active_record.rb
# this has to be here because we need MyClass, which isn't loaded early enough to do in environments/production.rb

Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  ActiveRecord.yaml_column_permitted_classes += [
    Date,
    BigDecimal,
    ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone,
    Time,
    ActiveSupport::TimeZone,
    ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess,
    MyClass
  ]
end
```

To be honest, you can also do this in `config/application.rb`:

```
    config.after_initialize do
      ActiveRecord.yaml_column_permitted_classes += [
        Date,
        BigDecimal,
        ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone,
        Time,
        ActiveSupport::TimeZone,
        ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess,
        MyClass
      ]
    end
```

Comment: NOTE: `config` gets passed into the `after_initialize` block so I just had to use `config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [ ... ]` inside of the `config.after_initialize` and I kept it in `config/application.rb` as well to keep it clean and consistent.

Comment: I’d suggest doing `+=` instead of `=` so that you don’t have to include `Symbol` and so that you don’t overwrite previous definitions that future Rails versions or gems may add.

Comment: Fair point @Sunny. Code edited.

Comment: I had this same issue on 6.1.7.6 and found that the classnames can be strings, so no   loader precedence issues. Just leave the config as-is and put quotes around your custom classes. 

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to set `yaml_column_permitted_classes` for a custom class is to use the `config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes` setting in `application.rb`. The issue you are running into is that the `application.rb` is loaded before the `Foo::Bar` class is defined. You can fix this by moving the `config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes` setting to an initializer that is loaded after the `Foo::Bar` class is defined. For example, you could create an initializer in `config/initializers` that looks like this:

```rb
# config/initializers/active_record.rb
config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [
  Symbol,
  String,
  Foo::Bar
]
```

This will ensure that the `Foo::Bar` class is defined before the `config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes` setting is evaluated.

Comment: Have you tested this? It doesn't actually work. With my way, when I start the console and run `ActiveRecord::Base.yaml_column_permitted_classes => [Symbol, String, Foo::Bar]` if I move it to an initializer it is returned as `[Symbol]` only. That's the entire problem (I tried it in an initializer)

Answer (score 1):

An all-rounded approach that worked for me in Rails 7.0 was this initializer:

```rb
# config/initializers/active_record.rb

Rails.application.config.after_initialize do |app|
  ActiveRecord.yaml_column_permitted_classes =
    app.config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes += [
      YourClass,
    ]
end
```

It’s a good practice to use `+=` in order not to overwrite the defaults that Rails or other gems might add.

Answer (score 0):

Moving this setting into an initializer worked for me. The initializer runs after my custom classes have been loaded, so I no longer get the `uninitialized constant` error. When I start the console and run `ActiveRecord::Base.yaml_column_permitted_classes` I see the full list I set in the initializer.

```
# config/initializers/active_record.rb
ActiveRecord::Base.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [
  Symbol,
  String,
  Foo::Bar
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify as strings. Works at least on 5.2

```rb
    config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = %w[Symbol Time Date BigDecimal OpenStruct CustomClass]
```